# Any way to limit physical memory usage? (Page file is OK)

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, memory, out-of-memory

I'm writing a program that requires more memory than my system has.

Is there any way for me to artificially put a limit to its **physical memory** usage?
i.e. Once it goes past the limit, the program should start paging to/from disk -- whether or not the physical memory is actually available. (That way the other programs I'm running can still run from memory and won't need to access the pagefile as often.)

Comment: I guess you've already made it the lowest priority process?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah but I really want it to be a limit, not just a priority.

Comment: A limit could be valuable to test how it would perform on a system with less RAM.  But just to protect other programs, I think priority is the right way.  You could also run the hog inside a virtual machine, configured for the amount of RAM you want it to have.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, still, if possible, I'd like to try it the "wrong" way to see which one works better. I feel there's a possibility that a hard limit might work better, so I would like to try it before ruling it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I just found the answer: [`SetProcessWorkingSetSizeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686237.aspx).

Comment: Note the provisos in the documentation: "attempts" and "if available memory is low".  In other words, the memory manager is still allowed to ignore the maximum working set you've configured if it thinks it best to do so - but this shouldn't be a problem, I believe it is fairly reliable and usually knows what it is doing. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: That part of the documentation was copy-pasted over from the documentation of `SetProcessWorkingSetSize`. If you look at the difference between the two functions you'll see there's a `QUOTA_LIMITS_HARDWS_MAX_ENABLE` flag that sets a hard limit.

Comment: Excellent.  I'd missed that.